# array_combine function is not displaying repeated values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

These are the values to be displayed.

```
print_r(array_values($price));
print_r(array_values($mec_id));



Array ( [0] => 3100 [1] => 1600 [2] => 1600 [3] => 3100 [4] => 7500 [5] => 3500 ) 
Array ( [0] => 47 [1] => 41 [2] => 42 [3] => 45 [4] => 46 [5] => 48 )
```

I need to use two arrays at a time in the foreach loop.

```
$combined_array = array_combine($price, $mec_id);
 foreach($combined_array as $price=>$mec_id)
 {
    echo '<br>'.$mec_id.'-';
    echo $price.'<br>';
 }
```

But, after using array_combined method, it is combining the repeated values too. I think it is parsing the array from ending while combining.

```
45-3100

42-1600

46-7500

48-3500
```

Comment: keys will be always unique in array, so duplicated values will not work in array combine..

Comment: My key here is $price which contains repeated values!

Comment: yaa you can not set duplicate values into index...

Answer (score -2):

You need to change order in array_combine so:

`$combined_array = array_combine($mec_id, $price);`

because you can not create the same index twice

Comment: Nice logic, Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :) But of course for 2 persons my answer was not ok... funny ;)